# How to control page breaks when we export report in word format

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report,when i export report in to the word format in ssrs 2008 r2 ,i lost my charts that are present in to the bottom of the report.I think this due to the page-break that occur.Please suggest me the appropriate solution about that.
please check the image of the report
[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide way more information. Tell us about your report structure, and explain what you've tried to solve the problem (and why it didn't work). Note that you can edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Hi I have attached my report image, i have 3 charts voice sms and data distribution but it is showing only the chart of the voice distribution

Answer (score 1):

Go to the properties for the chart and select "Add a page break before." Let me know if you are still having issues after doing that.

I would also try putting all of the items in a rectangle (and adding a page break before on the rectangle itself if necessary).

Comment: Hi I have attached my report image, i have 3 charts voice sms and data distribution but it is showing only the chart of the voice distribution

Comment: Have you tried my proposed answer of creating a rectangle, putting all of the charts within that rectangle, and then adding a page break before the rectangle (by going into the properties for the rectangle and setting the page break there)?